# GStreamer: a complete list of uri protocols?

Tags: uri, gstreamer

I see in various parts of the GStreamer documentation, and across the web, different protocols that `playbin` understands from the uri prefix, beyond `http://...` and `file://...`.

[webrtcsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rswebrtc/webrtcsrc.html) doc page shows `playbin3 uri="gstwebrtc://...`

[playbin3](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/playback/playbin3.html) doc page shows `playbin3 uri=cdda://4` and `playbin3 uri=dvd://`

I've seen `uri=rtsp://...` as well.

**Where do I find the complete list of these protocol prefixes?  Can you specify a video or audio capture device like v4l2src as a uri like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete list of URI handlers can be found by running `gst-inspect-1.0` with the `--uri-handlers` option.

For example, with `gst-plugins-base`, `gst-plugins-good`, and `gst-plugins-bad`:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 --uri-handlers

dv1394src (read, rank 0): dv
hdv1394src (read, rank 0): hdv
appsink (write, rank 0): appsink
appsrc (read, rank 0): appsrc
cdparanoiasrc (read, rank 128): cdda
dataurisrc (read, rank 256): data
fdsink (write, rank 0): fd
fdsrc (read, rank 0): fd
filesink (write, rank 256): file
filesrc (read, rank 256): file
curlhttpsrc (read, rank 128): http, https
pushfilesrc (read, rank 0): pushfile
testsrcbin (read, rank 0): testbin
dvbbasebin (read, rank 0): dvb
giosink (write, rank 128): file, resource
giosrc (read, rank 128): file, resource
imagesequencesrc (read, rank 0): imagesequence
multifilesrc (read, rank 0): multifile
splitfilesrc (read, rank 0): splitfile
splitmuxsrc (read, rank 0): splitmux
neonhttpsrc (read, rank 0): http, https
rsndvdbin (read, rank 256): dvd
rfbsrc (read, rank 0): rfb
ristsrc (read, rank 256): rist
rtmpsink (write, rank 256): rtmp, rtmpt, rtmps, rtmpe, rtmfp, rtmpte, rtmpts
rtmpsrc (read, rank 256): rtmp, rtmpt, rtmps, rtmpe, rtmfp, rtmpte, rtmpts
rtmp2sink (write, rank 257): rtmp, rtmps
rtmp2src (read, rank 257): rtmp, rtmps
rtpsink (write, rank 257): rtp
rtpsrc (read, rank 257): rtp
rtspsrc (read, rank 0): rtsp, rtspu, rtspt, rtsph, rtsp-sdp, rtsps, rtspsu, rtspst, rtspsh
sdpsrc (read, rank 0): sdp
srtclientsink (write, rank 0): srt
srtclientsrc (read, rank 0): srt
srtserversink (write, rank 0): srt
srtserversrc (read, rank 0): srt
srtsink (write, rank 256): srt
srtsrc (read, rank 256): srt
udpsink (write, rank 0): udp
udpsrc (read, rank 0): udp
v4l2radio (read, rank 0): radio
v4l2src (read, rank 256): v4l2
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a complete list of all URIs that are implemented in GStreamer plugins/elements.  One reason for this is that an element can be implemented external to the GStreamer projects and handle any random URI scheme.

What you can however do is retrieve the list of URI schemes programmatically.  An element exposes what URI schemes it supports using the [GstURIHandler interface](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gsturihandler.html?gi-language=c).  You can iterate over all elements that are available in order to see

1. if they support the GstURIHandler interface and
2. what URI schemes they support.

If you look at the gst-inspect-1.0 output for v4l2src, you will see that it also implemented the GstURIHandler interface and exposes a `v4l2` URI scheme:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src
...
URI handling capabilities:
  Element can act as source.
  Supported URI protocols:
    v4l2
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I do see this in `gst-inspect-1.0`.   The closest thing to a complete list seems to be searching the source code for `protocols[] =`  which is a common construct in the  `gst_..._uri_handler_init` call tree.